# URL Regex Matcher (Idea)

Tags: php, javascript, regex, url, pagespeed

Would it be a lot easier to make a simple regex for finding urls, then have another script to see if that site sends back data or not? I've always wondered if this would be a faster, and easier solution than taking years to develop the "perfect" url detecting regex, just to have it crushed a few days later.

If anyone can find speed tests for a basic page access/load, please post it here to help answer my question.

Also, how hard would it be on the server to constantly make requests such as this, say... 100 times an hour?

I am going to test this out with **Javascript**, using `/(http|www\.)\S+/gim` as the regex and a 60 second timeout connection to the requested url. I will do a simple ***"Title Grab"*** from the url, then record how long the trial takes. I'll post the speeds once I get them all fancied up.

This really isn't much of a question anymore, so if you find anything that really helps me with my above idea, you might receive the gloried *Answer Checkmark* for this "question.

Comment: It depends on how many urls you intend to find, and how long you are willing to wait for responses from remote web servers (which may be up, or down, or slow, or crashed, or whatever...)

Comment: A perfectly valid url can give a 404. A seemingly invalid url may be correct: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki///](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki///) - there is a big difference between 'valid' and "give 404".

Comment: @GregHewgill you could easily fix those with a timeout checker. 
@Kobi if you use a simple regex for urls, such as `/(http\:\/\/|www\.)\S+/gim`, you shouldn't have those problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point @Kobi was making is that **validity** of a URL is distinct from **presence** of a resource at that URL. A valid URL may not point to a present resource. For example, the URL http://bclennox.com/there-is-no-page-at-this-address will return a 404, presumably failing your test even though it's a perfectly valid URL.

At any rate, if you're primarily interested in the HTTP status returned for a given URL, you can just issue an HTTP HEAD request rather than a normal GET. HEAD returns a much smaller payload (only the headers), which should speed up your requests considerably.

Here's an example using `curl`:

```
$ curl -I http://bclennox.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Mar 2012 03:14:59 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.9, Enterprise Edition
ETag: "39cf7d1099a034de95dda297b18bfa2d"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Rack-Cache: miss
X-Runtime: 0.139410
X-Request-Id: 50ce319e403ef4e6e468c2f4b9817691
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: _master_session=BAh7ByIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMWZhM0t1dTZiNjVWV1Q3YzlKVTZmdjRwK0FiWlpHUExVWXJnRlovd2R5aU09Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiU3YWEzZmNhYmYzYTQ2MDgwNTY5ZmU5MjhlNWU3ZDhmMA%3D%3D--c0f8c2bd6cccb1ff12f28da996dddbb50e448f1f; path=/; HttpOnly
Status: 200
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: GET HEAD would be the way to go, though I think sometimes that is cached

Comment: So let's say this were http only usage, would the "url checking" method be better suited than trying to make a "perfect" regex, in consideration of time for the page to load, the message to load or whatever the implementation?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your requirements are. If you're mostly concerned with presence, then your test is fine: a quick sanity check for an HTTP URL, then hit it and see what it responds with. I would, however, recommend doing this asynchronously via Ajax or something, rather than forcing users to wait up to 60 seconds for a page to load with no feedback.